# How to automatically add a prefix to commit messages?

Tags: git

Is it possible to define a global prefix for all the commit messages relating to a specific repository ?

Comment: You could verify commit messages before allowing commit to proceed by updating commit-msg file. I could show you what I've done if this is what you want..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `commit.template` setting as discussed [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#_commit_template)

```
$ git config commit.template /path/to/git-commit-template.txt
```

This will set the template for the current repository only. You can add the `--global` flag to apply to all repositories.

Comment: This only works if you use `--edit` (`-m` or `-c` will override the template).